# Deploying my first app to GAE. (Could not sign in. & unable to find valid certification path)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, validation, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to deploy my first app to the Google App Engine but i am encountering the following problem:

Could not sign in to Google in eclipse. It says: "Could not sign in. Make sure that you have entered the correct verification code". I do not have a two step verification with the account i am trying to sign in. I also tried to change the proxy settings under the Windows->Preferences->Network Connections but that also didn't work.(I am in a corporate network)

I could run the application correctly on the local machine.

I also tried deploying it through command line using : `...\appcfg.cmd update war` . This gives the following message in the log file:

```
Unable to update:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.connect(AbstractServerConnection.java:125)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:138)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1326)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:327)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:121)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:117)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:425)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1326)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:327)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:121)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:117)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.connect(AbstractServerConnection.java:125)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.remoteRequest(ResourceLimits.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ResourceLimits.request(ResourceLimits.java:138)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:414)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of Kaspersky Internet Security 2015. Just pause Kaspersky protection until you deploy your war/ear, or just turn off "Web Anti-Virus" module.